# Change background color of selected text on WebStorm?

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

This is a really basic question, but I cannot seem to figure it out. How do I change the background highlight color of the selected text? When I select text with my cursor the background makes it unreadable. I have already searched in Preferences but couldn't find it.

[image: unreadable.]

Note: Using WebStorm 2018.3 on macOS Mojave.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing background color of **Editor > Selection background** in **Preferences | Editor | Color Scheme | General**

[image]